Regex with PHP and negative lookahead
I have this string aaa11 bbb1 cccc aaaaa22 bbb2 aaaa444 bbb4 cccc and I want to use a Regex that results into this:
aaa11 bbb1 cccc
aaaa444 bbb4 cccc
I tried this regex a+[0-9]+.+?(b+[0-9]+).+?(?!a+[0-9+]).+?c+ with preg_match_all but it returns:
aaaa11 bbbb1 ccccc
aaaaa22 bbb2 aaaa444 bbb4 cccc
I tried using negative lookahead to prevent a+[0-9+] in the middle but id does not work. How can I accomplish this?

Please state the rule that is to be enforced with a regex.  Why is b+[0-9]+ in a capture group?

If you wish to match strings that consist of one or more "a"'s followed by one or more digits followed by one or more spaces, followed by  one or more "b"'s followed by one or more digits, followed by one or more spaces, followed by one or more "c"'s followed by a word break, you could match \ba+\d+ +b+\d+ +c+\b. Demo

If I read your requirements correctly, the following pattern should work:
a+[0-9]* b+[0-9]* c+[0-9]*

Sample code:
$input = "aaa11 bbb1 cccc aaaaa22 bbb2 aaaa444 bbb4 cccc";
preg_match_all("/a+[0-9]* b+[0-9]* c+[0-9]*/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);

This prints:
Array
(
    [0] => aaa11 bbb1 cccc
    [1] => aaaa444 bbb4 cccc
)


Thank you so much! Maybe you can help me with this other similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78431088/regex-to-match-a-group-that-does-not-contain-a-specific-string but with a small difference.

Judging by the follow-up question, this was a poorly asked question, Tim.
